# Processing Data by Datatype in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a DataFrame containing int and str data which I have to process through.

I would like to separate the text and the numerical values in each cell into separate columns, so that I can compute on the numerical data.

My columns are similar to this:

[image: Showing A Snippet Of Dataframe.]

I have read about doing something like this through the apply function and applymap function, but I can't design such a function as I am new to pandas. It should basically do -

```
def separator():
       if cell has str:
           Add str part to another column(Check column), leave int inplace.
       else:
           Add 'NA' to Check column
```

Comment: Please do not include images in your question, but rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also is it always first int, then str? Or can it be anyway around? And are the int values actually saved as int? Or as str?

Comment: All your data looks textual to me, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @LeoE I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @LeoE Yes. It always starts with int then str. The values are saved as a str

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `extract` with a followed `to_numeric`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a_mrk4': ['042FP', '077', '079', '1234A-BC D..EF']})

df[['a_mrk4', 'Check']] = df['a_mrk4'].str.extract(r'(\d+)(.*)')
df['a_mrk4'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a_mrk4'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a_mrk4       Check
0      42          FP
1      77            
2      79            
3    1234  A-BC D..EF
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use regular expressions, let's say that you have a column (target_col) and the data follow the pattern digits+text then you can use the following column

```
df.target_col.str.extractall(r'(/d)(/w)')
```

you can tweak the re to match your specific needs